# linq to sql syntax different but should get the same results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I was playing around with expression trees and various Linq syntax.  I wrote the following:

```
using (NorthwindDataContext DB = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

            // Version 1
            dlo.AssociateWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID < 10700).Select(o => o)); 

            // Version 2
            dlo.AssociateWith<Customer>(c => from o in c.Orders
                                             where o.OrderID < 10700
                                             select o);
        }
```

The Version 1 method returns an error saying "The operator 'Select' is not supported in Subquery."

While Version 2 runs just fine.  From what I understand I am writing the exact same thing, but one is with the "dot" notation syntax and the other is query expression syntax.

Am I missing something here? Why the error on one but not the other "if" they are in fact the same query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Daniel's answer, the `select o` is known as a *degenerate query expression* - and it's removed by the C# compiler. So your query is translated to:

```
c.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID < 10700)
```

Note that without the `where` clause, however, the compiler *would* still include the `Select` call, so:

```
from o in c.Orders
select o
```

is translated to

```
c.Orders.Select(o => o)
```

From section 7.15.2.3 of the language spec:

> A degenerate query expression is one
>   that trivially selects the elements of
>   the source. A later phase of the
>   translation removes degenerate queries
>   introduced by other translation steps
>   by replacing them with their source.
>   It is important however to ensure that
>   the result of a query expression is
>   never the source object itself, as
>   that would reveal the type and
>   identity of the source to the client
>   of the query. Therefore this step
>   protects degenerate queries written
>   directly in source code by explicitly
>   calling `Select` on the source. It is
>   then up to the implementers of `Select`
>   and other query operators to ensure
>   that these methods never return the
>   source object itself.

Comment: Thanks to both answers and the great explanation Jon.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the `.Select(o => o)` in your query.